# Creating and pushing JSON data incrementally to frontend

Tags: java, jquery, json, rest, jdbc

I have a situation where I need to extract the sales record of 32K odd sales people in a co. and showing their total won, total pipeline, total forecast type of sales figure in the UI. I am reading the data from oracle db, and creating a JSON object of 32K individual items (data for each sales consultant) and exposing it via the REST endpoint. Once the json object is created, it gets called via jquery and gets displayed. But reading the data from db and fetching and creating a json object of 32K records take quite a while (around 15-20 mins) and my UI gets blocked till that json object is created.

My frontend contains an infinitely scrollable table, which extracts 200 more records on each scroll on the table.

I have tested the WS using 1000-1500 records and it comes back within 30 secs or so. So I want to create my middle tier object in such a way that it reads the data and continuously keeps updating the json object, by adding 500 more items or so into the json object and sending the updated version to the client. The UI layer that reads the data incrementally in scrollable table would gradually use the data anyway, and won't need all 32K records at a time.

Is there a way I can achieve this incremental update of the json object, which the UI can incrementally consume? Thanks in advance for your assistance in this.

The java class that reads the data and generates the array list containing the items looks like this:

```
public List<FLBDetail> retrieveFLB() throws SQLException, ParseException{
    FLBSqlQueries queryObj=new FLBSqlQueries();
    String query = queryObj.retriveFLBQuery();
    DataRetrieval obj=new DataRetrieval();

    ResultSet rs=obj.executeQuery(query);
    System.out.println(query);
    List<FLBDetail> domainList=new ArrayList<FLBDetail>();
    int i=0;


    while(rs.next()){
        i++;
        FLBDetail domainObj=new FLBDetail();

        domainObj.setRank(i);

        domainObj.setRep(rs.getString(1));
        domainObj.setDirects(rs.getString(2));
        domainObj.setRepOptyNo(applyNoFormat(rs.getString(3)));
        domainObj.setOptyNo(applyNoFormat(rs.getString(4)));
        domainObj.setTotal(applyDoubleFormat(rs.getString(5)));
        domainObj.setForecast(applyDoubleFormat(rs.getString(6)));
        domainObj.setPipeline(applyDoubleFormat(rs.getString(7)));
        domainObj.setUpside(applyDoubleFormat(rs.getString(8)));
        domainObj.setWon(applyDoubleFormat(rs.getString(9)));
        domainObj.setImgUrl(rs.getString(10));


        domainList.add(domainObj);
    }
    return domainList;
}
```

Now the service endpoint class converts the domainList array list object into a json array, by calling this method above and using the return array.

Also, this json object then gets called in $.ajax() frontend call, and gets bounded to UI elements.

Please let me know if you need any additional info.

Comment: pagination the data at the backend,implements a datastore that could get a page of  data from the frontend,and the datastore could cache loaded data & abort previous loading request if another new loading request reached & your table component could support show discontinuous data sets.

Comment: If you share your code we may help you more.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem where the client(GUI) used to do an extensive search based on wide criteria and the search result sometimes used to be too big to handle by the GUI adapter as it is. The way I solved this issue was by creating an active listener proxy which on every scroll of the data grid fired a rest call with previously send records' last identifier and brought the incremental delta result. You need to set a threshold and if the threshold is reached you use the above mentioned protocol. But remember, you are not making incremental DB calls, only the rest call to your service API which already has the data in-memory.